# MVC 5 TextBoxFor not able to do conditional Bootstrap CSS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a TextBoxFor and what I need to do is see if a property is NULL or Blank. If so then I need to let the end user type in their info. If not, meaning I can find their name, I need to disable the field so that they can not alter it.

I did some searching and try these two options but they are not working.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeName, string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.EmployeeName) ? new { Class = "form-control" } : new { Class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
```

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeName, new { Class = "form-control", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.EmployeeName) ? disabled = "disabled" : null }`)

Any ideas on what I can try?

Comment: could you possibly wrap your TextBoxFor control in an @if statement, then just check for the null property there? not really mvc but I think it could it work.

Comment: I'm sure I could do that but like you said I would think there would be a better MVC way of doing it. I'll do it that way if I have to but hopefully someone will have an idea on something to try especially since I have about 5 textboxes to do this on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code would be giving an error because there is no implicit conversion between the 2 anonymous types and you would need to cast them to `object`

```
var attributes = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.EmployeeName) ? 
    (object)new { @class = "form-control" } : 
    (object)new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeName, attributes)
```

Note however that disabling an control means its value will not be submitted, so if `EmployeeName` initially has a value, it will be `null` when submitted. You might want to consider using `readonly = "readonly"` instead.

Comment: I can work with that. I'll look into the difference between "disabled" and "readonly" but I'm having to store things like the Employee Name in a hidden form field already.